# Text is hiding under softkeypad in Webview when it is inside ScrollView

Tags: android, webview

Below is my main.xml file, where Webview is placed inside ScrllView to scroll if content is more.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svWriteScrollView"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webVi"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </ScrollView>
```

I am loading html content with contenteditable TRUE flag into above WebView.

Whenever i am typing more text with softKeypad, the text going below IME and whetever typing is not visible.

How to show the entered text above IME.

Thanks,

Comment: Doesn't a WebView already support scrolling? In that case I would say: ditch the ScrollView and probably Android will do the rest.

Comment: Hi Baske, actually in a scrollview i put different views including webview to scroll. I require the scrollview to scroll to the views, so how can i do that without scrollview...

Comment: Please add your complete main.xnl file

Answer (score 0):

Webview handles the scroll by itself. It is not required to put it in a scroll view. It will only disable the srolling in webview. 
As baske said If you remove the scrollview Android will handle the scrolling by its own

Comment: Actually in a scrollview i put different views including webview to scroll. I require the scrollview to scroll to the views, so how can i override scrollview and send event to webview to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is considered "bad practice" to put scrolling views within scrolling views.

1. Try to remove the ScrollView from your Layout and only keep the WebView (which will then handle scrolling for you).
2. If you really want what you have now, then as a last resort I would try to play with the manifest attribute android:windowSoftInputMode as I describe in my answer here:

[Can webpage be aware of android virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264465/can-webpage-be-aware-of-android-virtual-keyboard/15389957#15389957)

It is an unaccepted answer, but I think it was the most complete one. If playing with that manifest attribute doensn't help you, see (1) :-D